# PHP include and jQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page that shows a bunch of products and down the left hand side is a set of filters (e.g. colour, size, style). I originally had it so that when you choose a filter (e.g. green) it would post the form using the GET method and refresh the page with the filtered results. I'm now changing this so that it will refresh only the products content and not the whole page itself and I'm doing this with jQuery.

When the user visits the page with no filters selected, it uses a PHP include to show the initial results:

```
<div id="products">
    <?php include('products.php') ?>
</div>
```

When a user clicks a filter, I'm using jQuery `.load()` to load the the same include in its place but with the filters in the querystring:

```
$("#products").load("products.php?colour=green");
```

When it refreshes the products div, it does the PHP bit fine and only shows green products.

However, it still runs the PHP include under the filtered results which means I have the filtered results showing and then the PHP include results showing underneath and I'm not sure why!

I have to have the PHP include first so that if a search engine indexes by page, it will see there's content as search engines won't execute JavaScript (see answer to [Search engine visibility and jquery load function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688490/search-engine-visibility-and-jquery-load-function)).

### Edit

Here's my code.

shop.php

```
<form id="filterproducts" action="" method="get">
  <div id="filters">
    <p>Colour</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour" value="red" /> Red
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour" value="blue" /> Blue
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour" value="green" /> Green
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour" value="yellow" /> Yellow
    <input type="hidden" name="colours" value="" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="products">
  <?php include("products.php"); ?>
</div>
<script>
  $(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var colour = $(this).val();
    $("#products").load("products.php?colour="+colour);
  });
</script>
```

products.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, productname, productprice FROM products";
if (isset($_GET['colour']) && $_GET['colour'] != "") {
  $colour = $_GET['colour'];
  $sql .= " WHERE colour = '$colour'";
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY productprice LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
if (mysql_num_row($result) > 0) {
  while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
    extract($line); 
?>
<div id="product-<?php print $id ?>">
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.myshopsite.com/product/product-<?php print $id ?>" title="<?php print $productname ?>">
      <img src="/images/product-<?php print $id ?>" alt="<?php print $productname ?>" />
      <br />
      <?php print $productname ?>
      <br />
      <?php print $productprice ?>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<?php 
  } 
} else { ?>
<p>Sorry, there are no products to show</p>
<?php } ?>
```

I've only added the very basic code, just so you can see what I'm doing.

### New edit

I've tested the `.load()` bit by putting some normal text in #products and then running the click function:

```
<div id="products">
  <p>This is some test text</p>
</div>
```

When I click a filter, .load() replaces the

with whatever is in .load() so I know this bit works, it's just not removing the php include content...

Comment: What is your JavaScript code?

Comment: It sounds like the whole page is refreshing every time the filter changes, causing the PHP `include` to run again.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I don't think it is refreshing the whole page because my URL never changes from shop.php (even though my form is GET, no querystring is added to the URL).

Comment: I had just noticed I added it wrong, that was a typo by myself on stackoverflow! Oops... I've just corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<div>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['Filter']))
{
    echo $resultWithFilter;
}
else
{
    echo $resultNoFilter;
}
?>
</div>
```

You havent provide much code so its hard to know if this would work but maybe you could use the idea on another part of your code.

Comment: Instead of using two method to load the <div> use one that would handles different result sets

Comment: You could load both with .load("products.php") but you test if you have any $_GET[] if not display everything

Comment: Sorry, I've added the code to my post now so you can see what I'm trying to do - it is basic but this is how I start with code. @Sebastien as per the link I posted about search engines not executing jquery, I don't think I can do it all in .load()

Answer (score 0):

I've found out why it wasn't working... I was closing a div somewhere that wasn't opened!!! I feel so stupid right now but it goes to show that the HTML needs to be valid in order for it all to work correctly :)

Thanks for everyone's help though!